# Computing numpy array mean across axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape:

`(16L, 360L, 720L)`

How do I find the mean so that the resulting array has the shape `(16)` i.e. I want mean of all 360 * 720 values for each of the 16 axis elements.

I tried this:

```
np.mean(arr, axis=0)
```

but that resuts in shape of `(360 * 720)`

Comment: why don't you try something simpler to see the outcomes >>> a=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)   then use
>>> np.mean(a,axis=0)   varying the axes as 0,1, 2  and you can do combinations of axes like axis=(0,1) or (0,2), (1,2) and (0,1,2)  These will give you the possible shapes of means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does

```
np.mean(arr, axis=(1,2)
```

produce?

From the `mean` docs

```
   axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional
        Axis or axes along which the means are computed. The default is to
        compute the mean of the flattened array.

        .. versionadded: 1.7.0

        If this is a tuple of ints, a mean is performed over multiple axes,
        instead of a single axis or all the axes as before.
```